# WEI rating for Windows XP machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-experience-index

Is there a way to get a Windows Experience Index Rating (the one shown in Windows 7/Vista) on a Windows XP machine ?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/12/04/run-vistas-windows-system-assessment-tool-in-windows-xp/), you can perform the test -

> One interesting aspect of winsat.exe
>   is that it can also be launched under
>   Windows XP. It provides the same
>   functionality on that operating system
>   with the exception of the Windows
>   Experience Engine. What you basically
>   get is a benchmarking tool for your
>   computer system developed by
>   Microsoft.

The steps for doing this are described in the article.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to take into account that the rating between Vista and 7 changed, so the same values don't tell the same story between Vista and 7.