# How can I obtain a Windows Experience Index score for pc's running Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Getting a WEI  [Windows experience Index] type score on Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/192420/getting-a-wei-windows-experience-index-type-score-on-windows-xp)
>   [WEI rating for Windows XP machine](https://superuser.com/questions/172533/wei-rating-for-windows-xp-machine)

Does anyone know of a simple utility like the MS Windows Experience Index (WinSAT) that will run in Win XP ?

Failing that, can anyone help point me to a good site that publishes WEI scores of late 2006 vintage Notebooks ?

I am trying to get a WEI score for a Dell Inspiron E1405/640m where the weak parts are the Intel GMA950 IGP (Controller 945GM) and 1GB 533MHz DDR2

I did see a ref. that if you copy the Winsat.exe over from a W7 pc to a XP pc it works in a limited fashion. Anyone had any experience doing that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **winsat.exe** from Vista. More information in this [article](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/12/04/run-vistas-windows-system-assessment-tool-in-windows-xp/).

Comment: Its older laptops that came with XP, but claimed to be 'Vista Ready' that I want WEI scores for